# Repeated last row of query

Tags: ruby, dbi

I am using ruby-dbi to access a MS SQL database. The problem is that whenever I select more than one row from the DB, the result contains correct number of items, but all of them are the same, when they shouldn't be:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'dbi'
=> true
irb(main):010:0> db=DBI.connect('dbi:ODBC:dataSource', 'userName', '****')
=> #<DBI::DatabaseHandle:0xff3df8 @handle=#<DBI::DBD::ODBC::Database:0xff3e88 @h
andle=#<ODBC::Database:0xff3f30>, @attr={}>, @trace_output=nil, @trace_mode=nil,
 @convert_types=true, @driver_name="odbc">
irb(main):009:0> db.select_all('select distinct top 10 id from rawdata')
=> [[308], [308], [308], [308], [308], [308], [308], [308], [308], [308]]
```

The problem seems to be the as the one [discussed here](http://www.justskins.com/forums/problem-with-ruby-dbi-37368.html), but the solution proposed there (using `alias`) didn't work for me (or maybe I misunderstood it).

How can I fix this?

I'm using DBI 0.4.5, and Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows.

Comment: What version of Ruby-odbc are you running? http://www.ch-werner.de/rubyodbc/

Comment: I'm using ruby-odbc-0.2.5, which is the newest version on rubygems.

Comment: I mean, i'm using dbd-odbc-0.25 and ruby-odbc-0.99994.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, after realizing (at least partially) what was the post I linked in the question talking about, I modified the file row.rb from the source code of DBI:

I removed the code

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /^1\.9/
    def __getobj__
        @arr
    end

    def __setobj__(obj)
        @delegate_dc_obj = @arr = obj
    end
else
```

and the acommpanying `end` and I also removed the inheritance: `< DelegateClass(Array)`.

Answer (score 1):

That looks kind of strange because `select_all` are supposed to return `DBI::Row` objects. Try

```
rows = db.select_all('select distinct top 10 id from rawdata')
rows.each do |row|
  printf "ID: %d\n", row["id"]
end
```

Comment: That prints ten times `ID: 308`. Also `rows[0].class` returns `DBI::Row`, so I think that's what they are.

Comment: Strange. I presume that it's not when you execute the same query in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: No, that returns 308 on the last row, but other rows are different.

Comment: My best bet would be to try it under Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

I can only recommend: Go for TinyTds

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds

Its
  - easier to install and configure
  - faster
  - more stable

Comment: Yes, TinyTDS is way way easier. Just install the ActiveRecord adapter and use it, here is our wiki page too. https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds You can also just use raw TinyTDS for the connection too. What ever low or high level you want to go to, but DBI and ODBC are slow!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a MS-SQL database  with ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18)

This is how I solved it:

```
def myDBIexecute(dbhash,query)

  begin
    # open the connection
    conn = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:'+dbhash['datasource'].to_s,dbhash['username'].to_s,dbhash['password'].to_s)
    sth = conn.prepare(query)
    sth.execute()

    outputme=[]

    while row = sth.fetch
      mrow={}
        sth.column_names.each{|aname|
        mrow[aname]=row[aname].to_s
        }
     outputme << mrow
    end

    sth.finish

    return outputme

  rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
     puts "Error code:    #{e.err}"
     puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
  ensure
     # disconnect from server
     conn.disconnect if conn
  end
end
```